# Disruptive Ads policy

Tags: android, google-play, admob

Issue found: Disruptive Ads
We have determined your app contains code to facilitate Disruptive Ads.

Issue details

We found an issue in the following area(s):

SPLIT_BUNDLE 1003
About the Disruptive Ads policy
Disruptive ads are ads that are displayed to users in unexpected ways, that may result in inadvertent clicks, or impairing or interfering with the usability of device functions. Your app cannot force a user to click an ad or submit personal information for advertising purposes before they can fully use an app.

how I can fix it? I give up with it

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic

Answer (score 1):

Check the permissions you are asking for and also check the merged manifest file to look for permissions asked by imported libraries.

An important thing is if you allow clear text traffic, check your manifest and also your network policy file, I have had the same problem in the past and after changing the clear text traffic rule, Google Play has accepted my app again.

Manifest:

```
<application
    android:name=".YourApp"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="false"
    android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
    ...
```

network_security_config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
            <domain includeSubdomains="true">127.0.0.1</domain>
            <domain includeSubdomains="true">yourdomain.com</domain>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

As a last resort, use some translator and send the appeal in Chinese and Japanese because the support in those languages is better and they will explain the problem better with your app.

PD: If this helps you please write an answer to help other people with this problem because there is't not much information about this on the internet.

Answer (score 0):

I want to tell you and everyone here about the solutions I found for this problem

1. If you're using an app-Open ad and your app is getting pushed to the bottom and reopening for some reasons, such as backups, you need to fix this issue.
   in the MyApplication class change code like this.

> override fun onActivityDestroyed(activity: Activity) {
> appOpenAdManager.isShowingAd = true }

This way the ad will not be sent over and over again.

2. If you are using UMP SDK for GDPR, the old published examples are incorrect. Replace them with the newly released examples. Link:

https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-android-examples/tree/main/kotlin/admob

The biggest problem here

```
MobileAds.initialize(this) {}
```

If you call this code before the form, Google Play will return with the error you mentioned.

You can get this error for many other reasons. I tried very hard to understand the problem.

Comment: I am using only interstitial ads in application, is there any issue to open interstitial ads between after splash screen and before app home screen?

Comment: @GauravMandlik Maybe this can help you. https://support.google.com/admob/answer/6201362?hl=en&ref_topic=2936214